# Facing delay in sending images from Pi to computer using socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.9/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-network-stream here is the link with basic implementation.

From the Client(Raspberry Pi)side mounted on chassis/bot, images captured from PiCam are sent continuously to computer with GPU(server), socket connection is used for communication, and the method used in the above link was modified according to the need. At the server side, some processing is done, based on that few parameters are returned. Based on these parameters received at client side, corresponding action is taken by bot, and hence time is critical. However, im facing delay issue while sending images from client to server.

Part of code at the client(Pi) side

```
    def run_online_single(self, ip, port):
        client_socket = socket.socket()
        client_socket.connect((ip, port))
        connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')
        first_start = True
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            camera.resolution = (160, 120)
            camera.framerate = 30
            time.sleep(1)
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            for _ in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg', use_video_port=True):
                # start_time = time.time()
                self.send_images(connection, stream)
                self.recv_parameters(client_socket)
                if first_start:
                    self.contorller.start()
                    first_start = False
                # print('processed img ' + str(self.cur_img_id), time.time() - start_time)
        connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
        connection.close()
        client_socket.close()
```

```
    def send_images(self, connection, stream):
        """ Send images. Single thread, will block.
            Helper function for online mode.
        """
        connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
        connection.flush()
        stream.seek(0)
        connection.write(stream.read())
        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()
```

Part of code at Server side

```
    def listen(self):
        print('server: listening ...')
        # try:
        image_id = 0
        while True:
            new_img = self.recv_images()
            if (new_img is None):
                break
            new_img = img_process.standard_preprocess(new_img, f=False, binary=False)
            packaged_parameters = self.predict_and_fit(image_id, new_img)
            packaged_parameters_with_id = np.concatenate(([image_id], packaged_parameters))
            s_packaged_parameters = packaged_parameters_with_id.tobytes()
            self.s.sendall(s_packaged_parameters)
            image_id = image_id + 1
```

```
    def recv_images(self):
        """ Get image from the server.
            @returns
                return `None` if no more images
        """
        buffer_len = struct.calcsize('<L')
        #Delay Problem
        timer = time()
        buffer = self.connection.read(buffer_len)
        print('reading image length {:0.5f} s'.format(time()-timer))
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', buffer)[0]
        if not image_len:
            print('server: receive None')
            return None
        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(self.connection.read(image_len))
        image_stream.seek(0)
        file_bytes = np.asarray(bytearray(image_stream.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
        image = cv2.imdecode(file_bytes, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        return image
```

Delay problem occurs in reading image length, in recv_images() in this line:

```
buffer = self.connection.read(buffer_len)
```

which is just 4bytes length data, and its taking timings from 15-20ms in few cases to 90 to 130ms in most of the cases, causing delay, while the whole process actually takes 100ms odd(excluding this part), I'm trying to figure out why this is happening? Actual image data is downsampled grayscale image (160x120) and reading each image also costs just 3-5ms, but no idea why im facing delay while reading the image length. I'm new to socket programming also.

Comment: Try simplifying both sides of your code to work out what the problem is. On the sending side, remove all the image capture and just send a known, constant buffer repeatedly and see if the error persists. On the receiving side, just read the message length, print it and read the message and print the first 10 bytes discarding the rest. Try just using `socat` for each end of the communication as that is known, tested and debugged so invest in the time to write a dummy sender and a dummy receiver. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was planning to do that